Historical use of "reading" for Transportation
Seen in a print advertisement for D. & C. Line, dated 1914:

YOUR RAILROAD TICKETS, reading between Detroit and Buffalo or Detroit and Cleveland, are available for transportation on D. & C. steamers either direction.

I'm understanding the "reading" as a verb here, but can't find a modern definition to fit.  Was it a synonym of "riding" in the past century?

It is simply telling you the wording on the ticket.  How the ticket reads.

What is potentially confusing to a present-day speaker of English in this sentence, is not so much the meaning of 'reading', as of 'available'.

@jsw29 what I find confusing is railroad tickets for transportation on steamers. I think of "steamers" as referring to boats (eg paddle steamers) – in which case the sentence seems to suggest the tickets will be transported. That seems unlikely. I'm guessing that "steamer" here must therefore refer to a steam locomotive (i.e. a "choo-choo train"!), and the advertisement is announcing that the designated train tickets are now available.

Regarding the primary question, looking up a dictionary would have resolved the matter. For example, see MW, meaning 6.

It is a verb, but it is in the median voice.

I'm guessing that D&C steam boats will accept the specifically-mentioned railroad tickets as well as their own steamer tickets. Possibly they've done a deal with the railroad, maybe they anticipate railroad passengers buying additional things when they travel by steamer, or maybe they're just trying to get custom away from the railroad.

Yes, StuartF's interpretation is probably the intended one (the tickets issued by the railway can be used for travelling on the steamships); hence my previous comment that available is used here in a way that is not usual nowadays. It does not seem to mean that the tickets are available for sale on the steamships, but rather that the passengers who already have such tickets (because they bought them from the railway) can avail themselves of the tickets for travelling on the steamships.

StuartF and @jsw29 both correct here.  Perhaps it was no less confusing in 1914 because I found a similar ad dated 1915 that was revised to explain rail tickets "will be honored for transportation on D. & C. Line Steamers in either direction."  What baffles me is they further complicated the earlier expression with "Tickets reading via any rail line between".  What a mouthful!

It refers to what is printed on the ticket. You can get a ticket that reads "Between Detroit and Buffalo" or "Between Detroit and Cleveland".
Compare to 'The sign read "No Trespass"' and "The pressure gauge read fifteen kPa"

That makes more sense.  I wonder about the style and whether an extra comma would be helpful in the phrase "reading between".

Could use the quotes, not commas, that @dubious shows: Reading "between Detroit and Buffalo" or "Detroit and Cleveland," are available ...
